# How to fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 11.11.111.111:11

Tags: php

could any one help me to solve this issue.

fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 11.11.111.111:11(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Comment: Please post your code otherwise we have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that there's a server listening at IP address 11.11.111.111, port 11?

That seems like a very unlikely IP address, and a very unlikely port number.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- You typed the address correctly
- You typed the port correctly
- The service is running on the target machine, on the right port
- Your firewall is allowing outgoing connections
- Their firewall is allowing incoming connections
- You can route to their machine (try ping or traceroute)